# Function overloading with template

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, overloading, function-templates

I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void print(int& number){
    cout<<"\nIn Lvalue\n";
}

void print(int&& number){
    cout<<"\nIn Rvalue\n";
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){

    int n=10;
    print(n);
    print(20);
}
```

It works fine. But I want to make a function template so that it accepts both lvalues and rvalues. Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to change the input argument a `const` lvalue reference will do the job because rvalue references can bind to `const` lvalue references:

```
void print(int const &number) {
    ...
}
```

[*LIVE DEMO*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5fe1432c6e171a2)

Nevertheless, You could just:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T &&number) {
    ...
}
```

[*LIVE DEMO*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aeb7d34e5c0b646)

Comment: This is perfectly working. But what if i want to have two saperate print functions?? Or is it stupid thing to do??

Comment: If you want to have two separate print functions then you should have two overloads as in your example. However, from a practical point of view if you only want to print (i.e., not alter the input argument), a single function with input argument a `const` lvalue reference is sufficient.

Comment: I am trying to have two saperate templates for both print functions one with T& and other with T&& but its not working.

Comment: Yeap, with templates won't work cause the compiler due to certain C++ standard rules can't distinguish between the two overloads.

Comment: Then i guess i will have to live with only one print.. Anyway thank you so much. :) :)